# Change the startmenu entry "dynamic" for Windows Installer

Tags: windows-installer, nsis, graphviz, tortoisegit, orca

I wanna change the startmenu entry from windows installer packages, the *.msi installer, dynamic. (Tortoise Git, Graphviz) That means I need a switch or anything similar to change the entry while installing with the NSIS installer.

Til now I modified the Windows installer with the orca editor. But thats so to say a static solution because I can´t change it while installing with NSIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the startmenu folder from the local system after the windows installer is finished...